# Reading Data after Webpage is completely done loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, connection

I am making a login method on iOS that sends a GET request to a PHP page via url, when I try to read the output from the website, the data is read before the PHP can complete the mysql query, I was wondering if there were any way to wait until the webpage is completely done loading to read the data from it
code:

```
-(NSString *)getWebpageData:(NSString *)url {
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using `NSURLConnection` via `sendAsynchronousRequest` like so...

```
NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:myQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        //do something
    }];
```

It's mostly self-explanatory that when the handler block is fired you have your content.

Another option would be to invoke the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`. When you call your URL it will fire a few methods to let you know when things are done.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //Fired on error
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    //Fired First
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    //Fired Second
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //Fired Third
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //Fired Fourth
}
```

Using the delegate methods you're likely going to want to leverage `didReceiveData` so that you have your data right there. Good luck.